# Upgrading from 2013 to 2015 version of Kendo - issues with datasource items

Tags: kendo-ui

Have recently upgraded from a 2013 to 2015 versions of Kendo UI for MVC and am having a bit of an issue with datasource.  Can anyone point me at a place in the docs or elsewhere for a few examples of the differences.
Here is one link
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-data

eg:  The 2013xxx version way of setting the data

```
MyDataSource.data(data);   //where data was jason array returned from ajax
```

the 2015 way, at least that works but not sure if right

```
MyDataSource.data = data;
```

Also, as for setting values of dataitems, they too seem to have a different approach?
Old way:

```
var MyDataSource = $('#SalesGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource;
        var raw = statementBatchDS.data;  //raw will be undefined with 2015 version ???
        var length = raw.length;   
        // iterate and reset items
        var item, i;
        for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            item = raw[i];
            item.set("SaleAmount", 45.22);

//more code...
}
```

Now if I change the code to use Data, I get the data items, but then the dataitem set methods fail

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI Datasource has method data. Its not property so you use it as function. Data method gets or sets the data items of the data source.

```
var items = [
    { name: "Jane Doe" },
    { name: "John Doe" }
];

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({});
dataSource.data(items);
var data = dataSource.data();
```

So, change this line

```
var raw = statementBatchDS.data;
```

To this

```
var raw = statementBatchDS.data();
```